# toggling the div in THIS jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code

```
<div class="dish">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="title">рисовая каша с филе индейки и брокколи</div>
    <div class="add"></div>
    <div class="dish-info">
        <div class="info-left">
            <div class="dish-thumbnail">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="images/dish-pic.png" />
                <div class="dish-time">
                    <span class="time">45</span> <span class="minutes">мин</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dish-information">
                <h1>ингридиенты</h1>
                <p>700 г филе индейки</p>
                <p>1 лукавица репчатого лука</p>
                <p>1 морковь</p>
                <p>200 г риса «Арборио»</p>
                <p>1/2 л воды</p>
                <p>50 мл сливок 20%</p>
                <p>200 г брокколи</p>
                <p>1 пучок укропа</p>
                <p>Соль, перец по вкусу</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-right">
            <p>1. Филе индейки вымыть, нарезать мелкими кусочками. Лук и морковь почистить и нарезать мелкими кубиками.</p>
            <p>2. Положить нарезанную индейку в чашу мультиварки, залить водой и включить программу «СУП» на 1 час.</p>
            <p>3. После завершения программы «СУП» вынуть индейку из бульона.</p>
            <p>4. Бульон процедить и снова залить в чашу мультиварки, посолить, добавить укроп.</p>
            <p>5. Брокколи разобрат на соцветия. Добавить в бульон индейку, промытый рис и мелко нарезанные лук и морковь. Включить программу «КРУПЫ» на 30 минут.</p>
            <p>6. После завершения программы добавить сливки, перемешать и поставить на программу «КРУПЫ» еще на 10 минут.</p>
            <div class="add-dish"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are alot of `.dish` and `.dish-info`. When clicking on `.arrow`. It should toggle the `.dish-info` in that same div. It should not appear all `.dish-info`s, just the one which arrow is clicked. How can i do that?

Comment: Use DOM traversal to find the right elements: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/, http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.siblings(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), as `dish-info` div is a sibling of `arrow`

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".dish-info").toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wj76P/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(.arrow).on('click', function ()
{
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.parent().last().toggle();
});
```

Comment: (a) If you are only going to call `$(this)` once, then there is no need to cache the result in a variable. (b) `.parent()` will at most only return return one element, so `.last()` is unnecessary. (c) This would toggle the whole container, not only the corresponding `.dish-info` element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this jQuery-script:

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.dish-info').toggle();
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsz36/)

You can find more information about the nextAll-method [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: Its not smart to copy `my fiddle` and paste it as demo. more over in demo its `siblings` and the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree. **"dish-info" is not a child of "arrow"**

Comment: I know, copied the wrong URL as the demo. Plus, I'm searching for a working solution now :)

Comment: For the next time, I recommend you try your solution before you post it ;)

Comment: Thanks :) And I missread the HTML, I thought the dish-info-div was a child of the arrow-div, not a sibling. But next time I'll make sure to make a demo first before posting so I'm 100% sure my solution works.